# Is it possible to Transform a File that Contains 2 XML Files in it?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on a project and I receive an input that is 2 XML files appended to each other.
They still have the headers and everything.

What I want to do is use XSLT to manipulate this input and create a new XML file that contains data from both of the XML files.

Here is an example of what it may look like (this is one file):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root A>
    <data A1>
    </data A1>
    <data A2>
    </data A2>
    <data A3>
    </data A3>
</root A>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root B>
    <data B1>
    </data B1>
    <data B2>
    </data B2>
</root A>
```

What I would like as an output is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root Combined>
    <data A1>
    </data A1>
    <data B1>
    </data B1>
    <data A2>
    </data A2>
    <data B2>
    </data B2>
</root A>
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

And, if it is, can I do some data matching, like making sure that  has the same value as  and if so, put them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT can work with well-formed XML input documents and some processors also allow you to work with well-formed fragments. Your single input sample is none of that so you would to preprocess it to make sure you pass two well-formed documents to the XSLT processor. That assumes your sample contains well-formed markup at least and not stuff like `<root A>` which is not XML syntax at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am working with well formed XML, I just put the A and B letters in there to differentiate the different components of the input.